# Allocating a Thread's Stack on a specific NUMA memory

Tags: multithreading, pthreads, parallel-processing, numa

I would like to know if there is a way to create the stack of a thread on a specific NUMA node.
I have written this code but i'm not sure if it does the trick or not.

```c
pthread_t thread1;

int main(int argc, char**argv) {        
  pthread_attr_t attr;
  pthread_attr_init(&attr);

  char** stackarray;
  int numanode = 1;

  stackarray = (char**) numa_alloc_onnode(sizeof(char*), numanode);
  // considering that the newly 
  // created thread will be running on a core on node1

  pthread_attr_setstack(&attr, stackarray[0], 1000000);
  pthread_create(&thread1, &attr, function, (void*)0);

  ...
  ...
}
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: There are multitude of errors in your code. First of all, you are not providing the attribute structure to `pthread_create` and thus your stack allocation won't be used at all. Second, `stackarray` is defined and used in a very awkward way. Third, `numa_alloc_onnode` rounds the size argument up the nearest multiple of system's page size so your stack would be only 4 kB - is it enough?

Comment: thank you hristo for your reply. I've added the &attr to pthread_create. The size of the stack i've put it randomly. As for the stackpointer should i do this? :

Comment: char* stackarray;                                              stackarray = (char*) numa_alloc_onnode(sizeof(char), numanode); pthread_attr_setstack(&attr, &stackarray[0], 1000000);

Comment: You can just pass `stackarray` to `pthread_attr_setstack` - there is no need to write `&stackarray[0]` (although the result would be the same).

Answer (score 1):

Here's the code I use for this (slightly adapted to remove some constants defined elsewhere). Note that I first create the thread normally, and then call the `SetAffinityAndRelocateStack()` below from within the thread. I think this is much better than trying to create your own stack, since stacks have special support for growing in case the bottom is reached.

The code can also be adapted to operate on the newly created thread from outside, but this could give rise to race conditions (e.g. if the thread performs I/O into its stack), so I wouldn't recommend it.

```
void* PreFaultStack()
{
    const size_t NUM_PAGES_TO_PRE_FAULT = 50;
    const size_t size = NUM_PAGES_TO_PRE_FAULT * numa_pagesize();
    void *allocaBase = alloca(size);
    memset(allocaBase, 0, size);
    return allocaBase;
}

void SetAffinityAndRelocateStack(int cpuNum)
{
    assert(-1 != cpuNum);
    cpu_set_t cpuset;
    CPU_ZERO(&cpuset);
    CPU_SET(cpuNum, &cpuset);
    const int rc = pthread_setaffinity_np(pthread_self(), sizeof(cpu_set_t), &cpuset);
    assert(0 == rc);

    pthread_attr_t attr;
    void *stackAddr = nullptr;
    size_t stackSize = 0;
    if ((0 != pthread_getattr_np(pthread_self(), &attr)) || (0 != pthread_attr_getstack(&attr, &stackAddr, &stackSize))) {
        assert(false);
    }

    const unsigned long nodeMask = 1UL << numa_node_of_cpu(cpuNum);
    const auto bindRc = mbind(stackAddr, stackSize, MPOL_BIND, &nodeMask, sizeof(nodeMask), MPOL_MF_MOVE | MPOL_MF_STRICT);
    assert(0 == bindRc);

    PreFaultStack();
    // TODO: Also lock the stack with mlock() to guarantee it stays resident in RAM
    return;
}
```