# Moving or designating thread stack space in windows

Tags: c++, windows, stack, numa, multiprocessor

I'm doing parallel programming in a NUMA computer (I do not have the computer yet, it's scheduled to arrive soon™).

I have a pool of worker threads on each NUMA node (with processor affinity set) and a balancer that spreads work evenly among the pools/nodes. This is to ensure all memory allocations are on the local memories. This is all fine and dandy.

During start up the pool worker threads are created from the main thread and they have to do some inital setup before they can set their own affinities (3rd party library requirement, nothing I can do about it).

I'm worried that there will be a hidden performance penalty as the stack frames of the worker threads get allocated on the wrong nodes, causing foreign memory accesses.

Is this a real issue? Somehow I believe it has been solved already...

Anyway what I'm looking for is a way to make sure that the stack of each thread gets allocated on the correct NUMA node.

My dedicated google boy came up with this: [Allocating a Thread's Stack on a specific NUMA memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10605766/allocating-a-threads-stack-on-a-specific-numa-memory) which is kind of what I want to do, but it's pthreads and I need a windows solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a remarkable lack of information on this on MSDN, but given what I've heard Mark Russinovich describe when talking about windows memory internals I wouldn't worry about it unless I started to see a noticeable slowdown.

In the scheme of things even cross node memory accesses are still faster than say... swapping to disk. More importantly because the physical mapping of memory to active pages has no relationship with the memory space on windows (a purely virtual memory space), the kernel will likely remap the stack pages for each thread based on affinity.

I don't really think this is going to affect you, if it would there would already be an exposed solution because the SQL Server team would have run into it a long time ago.

Comment: Yes, the lack of info on MSDN is what tripped my alarm "what if they haven't thought of it?".

What worries me is that this performance penalty will probably not show up on any of the tools I have at my disposal so I'll have no way of detecting it. Hence I decided to pre-emptively ask here :)

"I don't really think this is going to affect you, if it would there would already be an exposed solution because the SQL Server team would have run into it a long time ago."
You would also think they would have figured out that removing the start button in windows 8 would be a Bad Idea™ but I digress :)

Comment: I really think you're over thinking this. Because windows uses a pure virtual memory space the page that holds your thread stack can be easily copied over to the new NUMA node (and probably would be even in naive copy on write semantics). This is beginning to seem more like a doubt that Microsoft has competent engineers than an actual question.

Comment: You're probably right and I'm not taking any silly measures just yet. I just want to be sure of this as I'll have no way (that I know of) to verify if this is causing a measurable loss in performance when I run it on the actual hardware (any day now, knock on wood). The lack of info on MSDN just has me legitimately concerned, as at least *I* would have documented this in the section about CreateThread or similar... had I been responsible for it.

Comment: I would highly suggest watching Mark Russinovich's talks on the windows memory manager on the TechEd site. He makes it quite clear that worrying about such minutia is largely not worth your time, as the memory manager takes advantage of the fact it can lie cheat and steal to your program.

Comment: am I missing something - googling NUMA and SQL Server seems to indicate that there are plenty of issues here (and many different attempts to address them)...  and there is a Windows API to SetThreadAffinityMask